# Recovering Linux Soft Raid6 with mismatching superblocks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, lvm, mdadm

My home lab server was half way through a RAID5 to RAID6 transform operation when one of my SAS cards decided to throw a fit in the middle of the night and cause 2 of the drives to be marked as unavailable.

Upon waking this morning and seeing what had happened I immediately rebooted the server and the drives were back but the array would no longer assemble or start.

First of all I checked the event counts on the 6 drives:

```
~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcdfgi] | egrep 'Event|/dev/sd'
    /dev/sdb:
        Events : 2691764
    /dev/sdc:
        Events : 2691764
    /dev/sdd:
        Events : 2691764
    /dev/sdf:
        Events : 2691764
    /dev/sdg:
        Events : 2679506
    /dev/sdi:
        Events : 2679506
```

After seeing that 4 of the drives had a matching higher event count and that non of them were the drive that was in the middle of being added for the RAID5 to RAID6 transform (/dev/sdg), I figured I should be able to do a force assemble with the 4 good drives:

```
~# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf
    mdadm: Failed to restore critical section for reshape, sorry.
        Possibly you needed to specify the --backup-file
```

Luckily at the beginning of the reshape I had created a backup file so:

```
~# mdadm --assemble --backup-file=/root/raid5backup --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf
    mdadm: restoring critical section
        mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md127: Input/output error
```

A look into the dmesg output wasn't much help:

```
[ 1194.472447] md: bind<sdf>
[ 1194.473147] md: bind<sdc>
[ 1194.473274] md: bind<sdb>
[ 1194.503167] md: bind<sdd>
[ 1194.504763] md/raid:md127: reshape will continue
[ 1194.504780] md/raid:md127: device sdd operational as raid disk 0
[ 1194.504781] md/raid:md127: device sdc operational as raid disk 4
[ 1194.504781] md/raid:md127: device sdf operational as raid disk 2
[ 1194.505026] md/raid:md127: allocated 6490kB
[ 1194.505136] md/raid:md127: not enough operational devices (3/6 failed)
[ 1194.505914] RAID conf printout:
[ 1194.505915]  --- level:6 rd:6 wd:3
[ 1194.505916]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdd
[ 1194.505917]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdf
[ 1194.505918]  disk 4, o:1, dev:sdc
[ 1194.505918]  disk 5, o:1, dev:sdb
[ 1194.506113] md/raid:md127: failed to run raid set.
[ 1194.507014] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 1194.507762] md: md127 stopped.
[ 1194.507766] md: unbind<sdd>
[ 1194.530614] md: export_rdev(sdd)
[ 1194.530653] md: unbind<sdb>
[ 1194.546595] md: export_rdev(sdb)
[ 1194.546637] md: unbind<sdc>
[ 1194.562584] md: export_rdev(sdc)
[ 1194.562625] md: unbind<sdf>
[ 1194.574586] md: export_rdev(sdf)
```

I thought maybe it would work if I tried to assemble it including the two drives with a lower event count:

```
~# mdadm --assemble --backup-file=/root/raid5backup --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf /dev/sdi /dev/sdg
    mdadm: restoring critical section
        mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md127: Input/output error
```

And a quick look at the dmesg output showed it didn't like that:

```
[ 1435.180559] md: bind<sdi>
[ 1435.199716] md: bind<sdf>
[ 1435.200403] md: bind<sdg>
[ 1435.200531] md: bind<sdc>
[ 1435.200660] md: bind<sdb>
[ 1435.200918]  sdi:
[ 1435.229950] md: bind<sdd>
[ 1435.230299] md: kicking non-fresh sdg from array!
[ 1435.230302] md: unbind<sdg>
[ 1435.251031] md: export_rdev(sdg)
[ 1435.251074] md: kicking non-fresh sdi from array!
[ 1435.251079] md: unbind<sdi>
[ 1435.267034] md: export_rdev(sdi)
```

Before I went any further, I took a quick scan of the disks into a file in case I needed the details later:

```
~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcdfig] >> /root/raid.status
```

Which brings me to the point where I completely screwed up, I tried to create a fresh array using the 4 good drives in the hope that this would see the data again:

```
~# mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=6 --chunk=128K /dev/md127 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf missing missing
```

However, after doing this, a pvscan/vgscan etc didn't produce anything, and a quick dd of the beginning of the array showed me that it was blank:

```
~# dd if=/dev/md127 bs=512 count=255 skip=1 of=/tmp/md2-raw-start
```

At this point I stopped the array again before any damage was done and no data should have been written to the array. Unfortunately this did change the RAID UUID for those four drives so it's now different to the two that were out of sync.

I've now stopped doing anything on the server and am hoping some fine person here can give me some guidance on how to proceed.

This system isn't backed up as it's my home lab server, however there is still lots of data in the array that I would prefer to try and keep rather than scratch it all and start again.